# After app is destroyed by the system it doesn't restart and Mvx does not start

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

When my app goes to background and after it's being destroyed to free up memory, it fails to resume/restart when bringing it to foreground, it's mainly been recreated on 4.2.2 and it does not always happen, sometimes it acts normally and restarts the app from the splash screen.
This is the screen i get:

[image: null screen]

This is the basic layout of the activity

```
<RelativeLayout>
 <LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
   <ViewPager/>
  </LiinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout/>
<RelativeLayout/>
```

The `ViewPager` contains an `MvxFragment` holding a `WebView`, the strange thing is that the app returns to this activity rather than the SplashScreen activity.
You can find the log [**here on pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/ExAhK4F4), the strange thing is that it enters some sort of loop when it fails to init the assemblies. Any suggestions regarding this issue?

Comment: Try to capture logcat messages during one of these failures (perhaps after adding more logging calls in your code to make it more informative).  It sounds like you may have a multi-activity design with an invalid assumption of always entering through a "front door" activity.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks! I'm looking into it now

Comment: @ChrisStratton Here is a hopefully more informative [log][http://pastebin.com/cDLikTbH], I tried to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY attribute with the main view which didn't help. After the app is destroyed it always ends up coming to the empty screen as described above, anything else?